# Cannot find ajax extensions in MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint

I have two questions here:

1) I am trying to implement AJAX in sharepoint.
   I have modified web.config as referred by:

http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/mike/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=3

but still i am getting the following error :

Unknown server tag 'asp:ScriptManager'.   at System.Web.UI.TagPrefixTagNameToTypeMapper.System.Web.UI.ITagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs) 
   at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType2(String tagName, IDictionary attribs, Boolean fAllowHtmlTags) 
   at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs, Boolean fAllowHtmlTags)

2) Secondly, i am trying to implement adrotator in sharepoint. I have tried installing the SPAdrotator but i am not able to display the images when i give the image library name as source in the "query" section.

Answer (score 1):

For Point #1:

Have you added this assembly to the GAC?: System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

The problem is that it can't find the scriptmanager class, which says to me that the assembly isn't installed properly. If it's in the bin directory of the SharePoint site, you would need to change the trust level (not recommended) from the WSS_Minimal default.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using .NET 2.0 or 3.5? The extensions downloaded for 2.0 are the much same as the ones included in 3.5, but the references in web.config will be different.

Easiest way to get the right details is to create a new ajax project in visual studio and copy bits from the web.config that creates for you.

2 should probably be posted as a seperate question, but it may have something to do with internal and display names.